# NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces - How to get connected COM port

Tags: c#, networking, serial-port, 3g, modem

Using the .NET method [NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces.aspx) I can get a list of all network interfaces on the computer (Wireless & cabled Ethernet and 3G modems (PPP)). From the information provided to me from this how can I get the name of the COM port used by the 3G modem (PPP)? E.g. COM4

Thanks for any help provided.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces only returns the IP based interfaces.

Unlike USB, the serial port does not have any protocol for identification of connected devices you will need to take a somewhat heuristic approach. For example, you can get the list of serial ports using [SerialPort.GetPortNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames.aspx) and then probe the ports with modem 'AT' commands to try determine which port the modem is connected to.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set) is a list of the basic AT commands, the 'ATIn' command might be of interest.